# CFPDF action="protect" ColdFusion could not delete the file

Tags: coldfusion, file-permissions, cfpdf

I do the following:

```
<cffunction name="GenerateTemporaryDocument" access="remote" returntype="string">
        <cfargument name="Source" type="string" required="yes" >
        <cfargument name="Fields" type="array" required="yes" >

    <cfset Source  = "\#Source#" >
    <cfset pdfName = ".\Generated\#CreateUUID()#.pdf" >

    <cfpdfform action="populate"    
            source="#Source#"   
            destination="#pdfName#" 
            overwrite="yes">

    <cfpdfform action="populate"    
           source="#Source#"    
           destination="#pdfName#" 
           overwrite="yes">
           <!--- 
           some form fields that get filled 
           --->
    </cfpdfform>

    <cfpdf action="write" 
        source="#pdfName#" 
        destination="#pdfName#" 
        flatten="yes" 
        overwrite="true">

    <cfpdf action="protect" 
         source="#pdfName#" 
         newOwnerPassword ='xxxxx'
         permissions = 'AllowPrinting'>


        <cfreturn pdfName>

</cffunction>
```

I'd say 99/100 times, it works fine. But every so often, I get this error on the line for the protect command:

> ColdFusion could not delete the file
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Generated\D6DBE4BD-AC16-2D87-C6CC1FDB990820C2.pdf.

Is there some obvious reason it would do this? If not, is there a way I can do a while loop and have cf wait for the file to become available?

Comment: Do you get any additional info if you wrap it in a try catch?

Comment: I could try that, what would I be looking for?

Comment: A more useful error message.

Comment: Is the code that you have shown us being executed within a cfm, or within a cfc which you haven't shown us? If the latter, and given that it is only failing 1% of the time, then you might have variable scoping issues only being seen under load.  Also, do you have any other processes running that might be routinely reading files in that directory, eg backup/robocopy scripts or virus scanners that might be momentarily locking files?

Comment: @SevRoberts This is the entirety of a .cfc. I do think you might be right about the backup or virus scanner, I'll look into that. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: It's difficult to speculate without seeing the whole cfc and how you're invoking it, but if this code is within a function within a component, and `Source` and `pdfName` have not been declared using the `var` or `local` scope, then there is the possibility for concurrent requests to contaminate that variable such that the value appears to change mid-request, for example resulting in one or more requests using the `pdfName` generated by another request.

Comment: Yes it is possible. If this code is inside of a function, then entire function should be shown. Also, variables really need to be scoped for a lot of reasons.

Comment: (Edit) *for example resulting in one or more requests using the pdfName generated by another request* ... in other words, the error might be caused by race conditions, created by lack of proper variable scoping. (Race conditions are usually sporadic).  Please post the entire CFC. Also, is the CFC stored in any shared scope, like `application`?

Comment: @ageax Like I said, this is the entire cfc, save for the arguments. And there can't be a race condition because the file where the conflict occurs uses a guid for the name. Unless CF has some issue where it duplicates guids, no two calls to this cfc should ever access the same file.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - I/O is just one aspect. The reason we keep asking to see the entire CFC is to verify whether or not you're localizing the function variables (pdfName, etc..). From what you described - you're not. Meaning if the CFC is stored in a shared scope - like "application", there absolutely *can* be race conditions.  Unscoped variables are placed in the default `varaiables` scope. That means if your component is stored in the application scope - the variables become *application* variables - which can be read or written to by multiple threads (cont'd)

Comment: ... and are subject to race conditions. Say Thread**A** comes along and starts the process by generating a new file name and starts processing that file (`pdfName=FileA.pdf`). At the same time Thread**B** comes along and changes `pdfName=FileB.pdf`, then starts processing it. Thread**A** continues its work and reads `pdfName` again - only now it gets back "File**B**.pdf" - and so both threads end up trying to modify the same file - at the same time. That's a race condition.

Comment: @Ageax I've added the rest of the function, but I still don't understand what you're getting at. Are variables declared inside the scope of function not automatically local?

Comment: @Ageax I can't believe I didn't know that... I would imagine that this is my issue. I'll prefix them all with local and see if that doesn't solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: No, they're not. Unscoped variables are placed in the default scope - `variables`. IF the component is stored in a shared scope, it's subject to race conditions.

Comment: **Edit** @PatrickSchomburg - *Is* the function actually stored in a shared scope - because it's marked `access=remote`? Sporadic errors like this generally suggest race conditions, but it still depends on how the CFC is being used (which I don't know).  Multiple http requests have to share the same instance of a CFC (i.e. component stored in the application scope, etc..) for race conditions to come into play.

Comment: @Ageax If I understand the question, no. It's stored in a mapped directory and has to be invoked each time using `new` or `createObject`

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg - If each http request *always* creates it's own separate instance of the cfc, then it shouldn't be subject to race conditions. However, you should still future proof the component by `local` scoping all function local variables. That'll avoids some nasty surprises down the road if you decide to optimize things by moving components into the app scope ...

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I found a suggestion by Charlie Arehart & others at

https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/i-was-not-allowed-to-deleted-them-pdf-s-until-i-had-restarted-cf/td-p/2435410

From Charlie Arehart's first comment:

> "You don't really need to create files with these CFPDF* tags

> ... you can use the NAME attribute
> (instead of destination) to indicate a variable to hold the output of
> an earlier step, and then use that variable in the SOURCE of a later
> step.

> ... may want to create the files intentionally, but perhaps
> at least if you only do it on the last step, it may resolve ... problem.

> ... /Charlie (server troubleshooter, carehart.org)"

and a solution by MarkMetcalf along those lines.